# MongoDB find using wildcard

Tags: mongodb

I have very little experience with Mongo and just cannot seem to get this query to work. I have a document that looks like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("51ee8dd79240dfb20a4f823a"),
  "value" : {
    "population" : false,
    "denominator" : false,
    "numerator" : false,
    "exclusions" : false,
    "antinumerator" : false,
    "patient_id" : "4fe1ece1a9ffcc03cd000efa",
    "first" : "Emilia",
    "last" : "Stronger",
    "gender" : "F",
    "birthdate" : -764708400.0,
    "test_id" : null,
    "measure_id" : "0024",
    "sub_id" : "c",
    "effective_date" : 1356930000.0
  }
}
```

I would like to perform a find that looks like this:

```
{
  "value" : {
    "denominator" : true,
    "measure_id" : "0024",
  }
}
```

But this does not work. If I remove any of the elements of this value object  or  replace them with wildcards, the find yields zero results.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is this about a wildcard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be quite simple:

```
db.collection.find( { "value.denominator" : true, "value.measure_id" : "0024" } );
```